# Frontend to write 'chemfig' code under Linux?

Tags: chemfig

chemfig for Latex is very good because it works on most Latex installation under Linux.

It is very complex to write anything.

```
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{
  HO-[2,.5,2]?<[7,.7](-[2,.5]OH)-[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[6,.5]OH)>[1,.7]
    (-[:-65,.7]O-[:65,.7]?[b](-[2,.7]CH_2OH)<[:-60,.707](-[6,.5]OH)
      -[,,,,line width=2.4pt](-[2,.5,,2]HO)>[:60,.707](-[6,.5]CH_2OH)-[:162,.9]O?[b])
  -[3,.7]O-[4]?(-[2,.3]-[3,.5]HO)}
```

Frontend to write 'chemfig' code under Linux?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What is your question, please specify? Please help us (and also you) and add a **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The OP is asking if some software exists, there is no need to fix any code, so why should an MWE be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Use a LaTeX editor with automatic preview as Gummi and test the formula in very simple documents (not within a thesis, for example)  so you will the check the the result of your changes almost instantly.

[image: mwe]

But at least for 2D formulas, check before if you can find a SMILES (or MDL molfile) formula for your molecules. Otherwise consider write yourself the SMILES formula. If you have the SMILES formula, it can be converted to the chemfig LaTeX format with [mol2chemfig](http://chimpsky.uwaterloo.ca/mol2chemfig/index).

For instance, the caffeine:

```
CN1C=NC2=C1C(=O)N(C(=O)N2C)C
```

Can be exported to:

```
\chemfig{-[:138]N-[:84]=^[:156]N-[:228]=[:300](-[:240](-[:180]N(-[:240]%
)-[:120](-[:60]N(-[:120])-)=[:180]O)=[:300]O)-[:12]\phantom{N}}
```

Quoting verbatim from that web page:

> Compared to hand-coded chemfig code, this generated code is a bit verbose and not particularly pretty, but it works.

Comment: There also is http://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig which lets you draw structures in a web-based editor and export that to chemfig code.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Good point. It is linked in the [mol2chemfig home page](http://chimpsky.uwaterloo.ca/mol2chemfig/index) but is worth  mention the drawing interface. As well as their searchable database, that is also a valuable resource.