# Chemical drawing software with latex script export

Tags: latex3, chemfig, chemistry, chemnum, structure

I have a query
Any chemical drawing software is available that is able to export the structures or reactions to latex script, and then compiled by a latex editor
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. // Sorry, can only guess what you want. But here's a reverse-route: https://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry . (Today as Halloween edition ...)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238760/simpler-way-to-create-chemical-graphs-using-chemfig

Comment: @MS-SPO thank YOU

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400775/frontend-to-write-chemfig-code-under-linux

Comment: @Fran Thank you very much

Comment: To convert molecules to "chemfig" format, there is "mol2chemfig" website https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655477/how-to-draw-structures-from-smiles-using-latex/655664.